# Trouble "updating SET configuration" in Linux Kali (virtual machine)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, kali-linux

The command is not coming back error but it does not do anything when I choose 5.

[image]

Choosing 4 gives this message:

[image]

This is on VirtualBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error on your second screenshot is telling you what the issue is:

> You are running Kali Linux which maintains SET updates.

The reason nothing happens when you choose option 4 or 5 is because it is setup like that. If you're running SET on Kali, SET will get its updates from the Kali repositories when you do a system update.

The problem in your case, I'm assuming, is the fact that you have not added the Kali Bleeding Edge repository. If you use just the main Kali repo your SET updates will be a few months behind on what the latest updates are out there from SET. All you have to do is add the Bleeding Edge repo and then update your system and SET will update to the latest version (I have just tested this out on a Kali virtual machine on my own system.

Do the following:

Open a terminal and run these three commands one after the other as root:

> echo deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge contrib non-free
>   main >> /etc/apt/sources.list
>
> apt-get update
>
> apt-get upgrade

Now reopen SET and you will see there is no longer a message telling you a newer version is available.

Comment: OK this is the command I used prior to posting this and I got back message from terminal toward the end as I guess it, im looking for the log file if thats possible.

Comment: echo deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge contrib non-free main >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade  this one

Comment: Did you get an error message or something?

Comment: If you ran exactly that command, that is wrong and you will get an error message when you run `apt-get update`.

Comment: yes and also a suggestion

Comment: Do you see how your command is different than mine? Your command has http.kali.org/kali and mine is http://http.kali.org/kali. You're missing that first http

Comment: Edit /etc/apt/sources.list and go down to the last line and correct it with that additional http in front like in my command. Then run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` again and it should update SET.

Comment: Oh! sorry yes I see, expect a response to all of this later tonight. I will try that out when im back home. thanks for the info

Comment: No problem. Please mark answer as Accepted if this fully addressed your original question. Thank you.

Comment: Of course, apologies. Im new here.